# my phone keeps reminding me of low space... any way to move apps and data to sd card?

Tags: htc-desire, insufficient-memory

My phone doesn't ask me to install to internal or external memory when installing an app. It automatically install to internal memory.. my phone keeps reminding me of low space and I can't install any other app cause my phone is low on space..... is there any way to move all apps and data to SD card? Any help......

Comment: I've just added the `insufficient-memory` tag to your question. You might want to check [its tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info) for more help on how to deal with that.

Answer (score 1):

Use this App to move your apps from Internal storage to Sd Card https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.IQBS.android.app2sd

Comment: Yea... what about moving data to SD card? some apps are installed on internal memory directly and cannot be moved... is there also a way to move them?

Answer (score 0):

These two apps will help you clear out some extra space, too. They work best when the phone is rooted, but are still useful even if it isn't.

SD Maid:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.thedarken.sdm

Root App Delete:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=zsj.android.uninstall

I use them on my rooted HTC Evo 4g lte and rooted Kindle Fire HDX 7"

Comment: As far as moving data that says "non-moveable" you can force move it sometimes (may require root) using esfile explorer (under options check "show hidden" and then linking to it with Link2SD.  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.buak.Link2SD